# Is this mandatory to create branch in svn like git

Tags: svn

suddenly i have shifted to svn from git and working on svn. So here i have one doubt pertaining to creation of branch in svn is mandatory like git for commit, push, and merge.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: After modifications in git,  i usually create a branch, add necessary files and commit. while doing so not effected to current repo in git...............Here i got doubt, am i need to do like in svn to create branch, add files, and commit.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can use Trunk-Only workflow (and a lot of headache with reverse-merge on "bad" commits)